# Combination of tests and custom build directory

Tags: c++, c, compilation, autotools

I'm running into an issue with autotools.

I need both the support for tests and custom build directory (other then the main source directory). Autotools seems to complain:

`src/lib/Libattr/test/attr_atomic/Makefile.am:18: error: using '$(top_srcdir)' in TESTS is currently broken: '$(top_srcdir)/src/test/coverage_run.sh'`

Apparently the same thing is true for `$(srcdir)`. The unit test needs to have manually set includes and source paths as it requires headers and files from different locations in the source tree.

How do I refer to the root of the source tree if I can't use `$(srcdir)` and `$(top_srcdir)`?

Answer (score 0):

I suspect the problem is that your autotooled test harness plays by the
rules of the [Older (and discouraged) serial test harness](http://www.gnu.org/software/automake/manual/html_node/Serial-Test-Harness.html#Serial-Test-Harness)
and that the solution is to play by the rules of the newer and correspondly
encouraged [Parallel Test Harness](http://www.gnu.org/software/automake/manual/html_node/Parallel-Test-Harness.html#Parallel-Test-Harness)

In the latter, as you'll gather from the example code at the link, you don't mention `$(top_srcdir)` *et al* in `TESTS`. You
mention them in `AM_TESTS_ENVIRONMENT`:

Here's an illustrative `Makefile.am` fragment to hand that works fine for me:

```
...
CORE_TESTS = coan_case_tester.py coan_bulk_tester.py coan_spin_tester.py \
coan_symbol_rewind_tester.py coan_softlink_tester.py
if MAKE_CHECK_TIMING
TESTS = $(CORE_TESTS) coan_test_metrics.py
else
TESTS = $(CORE_TESTS)
endif

AM_TESTS_ENVIRONMENT = COAN_PKGDIR=$(top_srcdir); \
    COAN_BUILDDIR=$(top_builddir); TIMING_METRICS=$(TIMING_METRICS_ENABLED); \
    rm -f coan.test_timer.time.txt; \
    export COAN_PKGDIR; export COAN_BUILDDIR; export TIMING_METRICS;
LOG_COMPILER = python
```

Comment: Could you give me more information. The problem is that if I understand this correctly, I would put the `AM_TESTS_ENVIRONMENT` definition in the same file where I already don't have access to `$(top_srcdir)`.